# use tuple as index in pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very simple task. Essentially, I want to create a pandas Series and use tuple values as index. For example,

```
series_tmp = pd.Series()
series_tmp[(0,'a')] = 1
```

What I want to do is that, I want to create one more row in the pd.Series, whose index is (0,'a') and whose value is 1.

The above code gets the error:

```
KeyError: '[0 1] not in index'
```

Any help?

I know about multi-index, but it cannot help my case. Because I need to have very complex tuples like ('a',(2,'c'),'d') as a key.

**Conclusion**: Thanks for all the wonderful answers! To add a row with tuple as index, we should do:

```
series_tmp = series_tmp.append(pd.Series([1],index=[(0,'a')]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating a series object with a multi-index from data, you can do so by constructing a dictionary with tuples as keys, and the data as values.  Then pass that to the series constructor.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {(0,'a'):1, (0,'b'):1.5, (1,'a'):3, (1,'b'):3.5}
s = pd.Series(d)
s
# returns:
0  a    1.0
   b    1.5
1  a    3.0
   b    3.5
dtype: float64
```

---

### Edit based on comments:

For this situation, an index of explicit tuples is required.  In that case, you can construct the index ahead of time, then use that as the `index` parameter when constructing the series.

```
ix = pd.Index([(1,'a'), ('a',(2,'b')), (2,('b',1))])
s = pd.Series(data=[1,5,9], index=ix)
s
# returns:
(1, a)         1
(a, (2, b))    5
(2, (b, 1))    9
dtype: int64

# check indexing into the series object
s[('a',(2,'b'))]
# returns:
5
```

Comment: I know about multi index, but in my application, I need to use an actual tuple within a cell... Because I will have very complex tuple like ('a',(2,'b')) as a key....

Comment: So you need an index with explicit tuples?

Comment: Thanks! in this case, the best way to add an element is to use append with a new pd.Series?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('0', 'a'), ('1', 'b')]))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
       a    b
0 a  NaN  NaN
1 b  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I know about multi index, but in my application, I need to use an actual tuple within a cell... Because I will have very complex tuple like ('a',(2,'b')) as a key....

Answer (score 1):

```
In :series_tmp = pd.Series([5,6],index=[(0,'a'),(1,'b')])
    series_tmp
Out:(0, a)    5
    (1, b)    6
    dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is problematic if you add a duplicate value, then the indexing doesn't work anymore:

```
s = pd.Series()
s = s.append(pd.Series([1],index=[(0,'a')])).append(pd.Series([0],index=[(0,'a')]))
s[(0, 'a')]
```

That would raise a `KeyError: 'key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex'`

I would consider to use `repr` to convert tuples:

```
s = pd.Series()
s[repr((0, 'a'))] = 1
s[repr((0, 'a'))] = 0
s[repr((0, 'a'))]
```